# Adding a space between spans so that the string looks normal even after removing the spans

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a piece of my code. Using a for loop I wrap each of `spanPhrases` elements with a specific span with its `id` and `class` and then add them as a single sentence to the page.

After 2 seconds (using jQuery) I remove the spans while I maintain the whole sentence like this:

```
// After 2 seconds remove spans and maintain text
$('#answerSentence').find(".spans").contents().unwrap();
```

The issue is I can't find a way to add a space between spans so that the sentence looks normal. So far there is no space between spans and only when we remove spans in the `removeSpans` function the sentence looks normal in case of word spacing.

I want no change in word spacing after 2 seconds.

Note: I want `answerSentence` in the `removeSpans` function without any `&nbsp`

```js
let answerPhrases = ['i was sent', 'to earth', 'to live'];


let spanPhrases = ["I was sent", " to Earth,", " to live."];
let answer = '';

// put each of spanPhrases into a span with id and class
for (let i = 0; i < spanPhrases.length; i++) {

  answer += `<span class='spans' id='spanID${i}'>${spanPhrases[i]}</span>`;

};

// add the text with spans to the page
answerSentence.innerHTML = `${answer}`;


setTimeout(function() {

  removeSpans();

  function removeSpans() {
    // After 2 seconds remove spans and maintain text
    $('#answerSentence').find(".spans").contents().unwrap();
  }


}, 2000)
```

```css
.containerAnswering {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 9.5vw;
  top: 48vh;
  height: 29vh;
  width: 82vw;
  outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}

.answerSentence-class {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  left: 0.5vw;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 4vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="containerAnswering">
  <div id="answerSentence" class="answerSentence-class"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not change your text wrapping to `pre-wrap`?

```js
let answerPhrases = ['i was sent', 'to earth', 'to live'];


let spanPhrases = ["I was sent", " to Earth,", " to live."];
let answer = '';

// put each of spanPhrases into a span with id and class
for (let i = 0; i < spanPhrases.length; i++) {

  answer += `<span class='spans' id='spanID${i}'>${spanPhrases[i]}</span>`;

};

// add the text with spans to the page
answerSentence.innerHTML = `${answer}`;


setTimeout(function() {

  removeSpans();

  function removeSpans() {
    // After 2 seconds remove spans and maintain text
    $('#answerSentence').find(".spans").contents().unwrap();
  }


}, 2000)
```

```css
.containerAnswering {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 9.5vw;
  top: 48vh;
  height: 29vh;
  width: 82vw;
  outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}

.answerSentence-class {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-wrap; // Update text wrap
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  left: 0.5vw;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 4vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="containerAnswering">
  <div id="answerSentence" class="answerSentence-class"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript is correct. You should fix CSS styles. This weird behavior disappears if replace `display: flex; align-items:center;` with `line-height: 29vh;`(to be aligned within parent container) in `.answerSentence-class`.

I would change that CSS as follows:

```
.answerSentence-class {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  left: 0.5vw;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 4vh;
  line-height: 29vh;
}
```

Unfortunately I have no answer why does flex truncate spaces.